# Importing project from Visual Studio Mac to Rider

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms, rider

I have been trying to import my Xamarin.Forms project to Rider but the IDE doesn't seem to detect some system paths.
Data types like `string`, `void`, `bool` are not recognised, imports like `System.Threading` is not detected at all (though some imports are, like `System.Net`).
Does anyone have an idea what is going on?

Here are a couple screenshots:
[image]
[image: Build settings]

Comment: try to change msbuild to a mono's one

Comment: I do not think .net core msbuild has xamarin sdk inside =)

Comment: Restore NuGet packages and rebuild.

Comment: Changing msbuild worked although Rider couldn't figure out the XAML and code-behind relations at first. If either of you adds your comment as an answer I'll accept it.